# Using scanner.next() to return the next n number of characters

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use a scanner to parse out some text but i keep getting an InputMismatchException. I'm using the scanner.next(Pattern pattern) method and i want to return the next n amount of characters (including whitespace).

For example when trying to parse out

```
"21        SPAN 1101"
```

I want to store the first 4 characters (`"21  "`) in a variable, then the next 6 characters (`"      "`) in another variable, then the next 5 (`"SPAN "`), and finally the last 4 (`"1101"`)

What I have so far is:

```
String input =  "21        SPAN 1101";
Scanner parser = new Scanner(input);
avl = parser.next(".{4}");
cnt = parser.next(".{6}");
abbr = parser.next(".{5}");
num = parser.next(".{4}");
```

But this keeps throwing an InputMismatchException even though according to the java 8 documentation for the scanner.next(Pattern pattern) it doesn't throw that type of exception. Even if I explicitly declare the pattern and then pass that pattern into the method i get the same exception being thrown.

Am I approaching this problem with the wrong class/method altogether? As far as i can tell my syntax is correct but i still cant figure out why im getting this exception.

Comment: I'm getting some major XY problem vibes from this question. Why are you trying to capture a seemingly arbitrary number of spaces from your input?

Comment: @Pshemo Your comment definitely looks worthy of being an answer to me.

Comment: If you know your lengths, why not use `input.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`?

Answer (score 3):

At documentation of [`next(String pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next-java.lang.String-) we can find that it (emphasis mine)

> Returns the next token **if it matches the pattern constructed from the specified string**.

But `Scanner` is using as default delimiter *one or more whitespaces* so it doesn't consider spaces as part of token. So first token it returns is `"21"`, not `"21  "` so condition "...if it matches the pattern constructed from the specified string" is not fulfilled for `.{4}` because of its length.

Simplest solution would be reading entire line with `nextLine()` and splitting it into separate parts via regex like `(.{4})(.{6})(.{5})(.{4})` or series of substring methods.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider creating a convenience method to cut your input String into variable number of pieces of variable length, as approach with `Scanner.next()` seems to fail due to not considering spaces as part of tokens (spaces are used as delimiter by default). That way you can store result pieces of input String in an array and assign specific elements of an array to other variables (I made some additional explanations in comments to proper lines):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String input =  "21        SPAN 1101";
    String[] result = cutIntoPieces(input, 4, 6, 5, 4);

    // You can assign elements of result to variables the following way:
    String avl = result[0];  // "21  " 
    String cnt = result[1];  // "      "
    String abbr = result[2]; // "SPAN "
    String num = result[3];  // "1101"

    // Here is an example how you can print whole array to console:
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result)); 
}

public static String[] cutIntoPieces(String input, int... howLongPiece) {
    String[] pieces = new String[howLongPiece.length]; // Here you store pieces of input String
    int startingIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < howLongPiece.length; i++) { // for each "length" passed as an argument...
        pieces[i] = input.substring(startingIndex, startingIndex + howLongPiece[i]); // store at the i-th index of pieces array a substring starting at startingIndex and ending "howLongPiece indexes later"
        startingIndex += howLongPiece[i]; // update value of startingIndex for next iterations
    }
    return pieces; // return array containing all pieces
}
```

Output that you get:

```
[21  ,       , SPAN , 1101]
```